# Post Data to Object Type Data Member in WCF using C#

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

Below is the code (Required DTOs)

```
[KnownType(typeof(LocateReceive))]
[DataContract]
public class CommandReceiver : MessageCommand
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CommandKey { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MAC { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public object Response { get; set; } // Need help here, it should hold object reference of known types
}

[DataContract]
public class MessageCommand
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 MessageCommandId { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class LocateReceive
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want Response Data Member can hold Object of LocateReceive when pushed via ajax (i am using fiddler for same).

Below is the request body sent from fiddler:

```
{
"MessageCommandId":9223372036854775807,
"CommandKey":"String content",
"MAC":"String content",
"Response":{
    "Latitude":"String content",
    "Longitude":"String content"
}}
```

> Getting Error: Bad Request

Ultimately I want Response data member can hold/convert n number of class object passed in ajax.

Comment: the JSON looks ok, but that's not necessarily the only reason to get a Bad Request. Is there no more error detail, e.g. in the response body? Ideally we need to see both your ajax code and your service method which receives the request.

Comment: I would have thought `public object Response { get; set; }` ought to be `public LocateReceive Response { get; set; }` as well, otherwise the JSON deserialiser won't be able to populate the properties correctly, it will see that your type is `object`, and since `object` has no properties, it will discard the latitude and longitude values from the JSON because they don't match to any properties of the class.

Comment: @ADyson , yes you are right. I know that way but i want to make my Response method generic otherwise i need to write code for every command. I need to find some other way out...

Comment: @ADyson, why KnownType is not working? do you have any idea?

Comment: you could try using the `dynamic` type. But I don't quite get your meaning. If you're sending different types of data to the server in different circumstances, then it's normal to have different methods to receive the data - normally you want to perform different operations on it anyway so it makes sense. As a simple example if you have "Employees" and "Rooms" in your organisational database, you'd have methods "AddEmployee" and "AddRoom", expecting different types. You wouldn't have "AddData" and expect the server to work out what type of data it is, and thus what to do with it.

Comment: I could be on the wrong track with what you're doing, but writing a few different methods to receive different data types isn't unreasonable and is what most applications/services do. Then it's also clear to the sender what they can / can't send to each method, and it's easily documented as well.

Comment: P.S. Were you able to determine if this was in fact the cause of the Bad Request or not? (See my first comment)

Comment: @ADyson, yes Bad Request was only due to that. `public LocateReceive Response { get; set; }` works well.

Comment: what if i generally wants to know how it could be done? May be somewhere i could only left with this choice only !!  I can opt for creating multiple methods accepting their own parameters but there should be some way out.

Comment: well, there's `dynamic` as I suggested before. That's probably the closest way. And why should there be a "way out". It's not a bad situation that you're in, it's perfectly normal. Almost all APIs work with separate methods for the separate data types. Just have a look at the docs for some public ones like Google or whoever. I can't really imagine a situation where you'd have "no choice" but to create some generic Frankenstein method to accept multiple data types in one method. It's purely a design choice for you. Really creating a few different methods is not a big overhead if you do it right

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks man for making my mind. Cheers...